# Comparing pimpl idiom with Microsoft COM

Tags: c++, interface, com, dynamic-linking, pimpl-idiom

I know this topic is somewhat off-topic on StackOverflow. But I just cannot think of another more appropriate place to post it, and I really want to gather opinions from you guys.

Recently, I come across the [pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). I think it is related to Microsoft's [Component Object Model (COM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), and trying to make a comparison of the two. Such a comparison should be beneficial to the understanding, and I want to make sure that I get it right. So, if you find any misunderstanding in the comparison or have any additions to make, feel free to post it as an answer. The comparison is as follows:

#### Similarities:

1. Both of the two decouple interface from implementation at the binary
   level. Therefore, changing the implementation does not require
   recompiling user code.

#### Differences:

1. Since COM interfaces use virtual functions only, user code can be
   compiled and linked independently without referencing the
   implementation in any way. This enables the binary module (i.e.,
   `.dll` on Windows and `.so` on Linux) of the implementation to be
   dynamically loaded at demands during process running (e.g., through
   explicit calls to `LoadLibrary()` on Windows platforms). With the
   pimpl idiom, class methods are not necessarily virtual, and user
   code linking has to reference the implementation, or there will be
   unresolved external symbol references. Besides, loading of the
   implementation binary module has to be done implicitly at process
   startup by the operating system loader.
2. The pimpl idiom allows instantiating implementation objects directly
   in user code. With COM, however, a factory function has to be used
   to obtain a pointer to the implementation object.
3. While COM is designed to be compiler-neutral, the pimpl idiom is not
   because of name-mangling and such.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is perhaps better served at being a wiki topic

Comment: @Roy Any suggestion as to where I should post things like this?

Comment: No sadly.  I did hover on the _"belongs on another site"_ radio button choice but could not think of one.  Other than that I don't think it is a _bad_ question. :)

Comment: The goal of PIMPL is simple: to hide the implementation details of a class to get better encapsulation. COM is much more grandiose: it enables an object to support multiple interfaces, and allows those objects to exist in the same executable, in a DLL, in a different executable, or on a different machine entirely, without the calling code needing to be aware of the difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree. COM is far more comprehensive than the pimpl idiom. I mainly concentrate on the binary interface (firewall) aspect. Anyway, did you find any misunderstanding in the differences given in the question?

Comment: Why are you comparing COM with PIMPL, while COM is a 1-to-1 mapping to abstract class?

Comment: @SergeyA Since in my opinion, the ultimate motivations driving the two are both binary-level interface and implementation separation, and I want to know the similarities and differences of them in this regard.

Comment: The ultimate motivation begind COM was to introduce abstract class idea to languages not supporting it natively, Visual Basic most and foremost. There is nothing more to it.

Answer (score 2):

Both are voluntary restrictions on allowed constructs in the code, to achieve a particular goal.

The common element of both is that they enforce a hard distinction between pure data structures (that cannot contain methods) and object interfaces (that cannot contain data members).

COM, in addition, also requires data and interface parameters to be serializable (with some exceptions, e.g. `IUnknown` is not), and also introduces a second naming convention for classes using GUIDs and a binary interface specifying data structure and virtual function table layout.

The pimpl idiom also uses factory classes -- the pimpl class creates the actual implementation. COM just explicitly calls them factory classes, and permits reuse of objects (for example, it is legal for a factory class providing a singleton to simply return a reference to itself).

Personally, I find the pimpl idiom unnecessary. The class holding the implementation pointer is a fairly verbose smart pointer class that explicitly replicates all methods, and the only advantage it provides over an `auto_ptr` to an abstract class with a `virtual` destructor is that it allows to use `.` instead of `->` to access methods.

COM adds new functionality:

- method calls can be marshalled and transported to different execution contexts
- all objects contain a reference counter, which allows sharing of objects between non-cooperating contexts
- runtime dispatch is performed through GUIDs, which allows altering interface definitions without compatibility issues as long as the old GUID is still recognized and a compatibility layer loaded
- objects can be composed of different sub-objects, but pretend to be a larger single object to the caller.
- the common binary interface and restrictions on memory allocation allow calls between code generated with different compilers, and even linked against different implementations of the runtime

The marshalling aspect is the most important one, as the execution context of the callee may be a different, privileged process that provides a system service.

Comment: Could you elaborate on some distinctions with respect to their practical use (capabilities)?